# Program stuck on PreparedStatement the second time it comes to it

Tags: java, jdbc

I am writing a program that connects to a database also used by another different program so I need to make a quick consult then close the database and repeat this process each few seconds with a timer. My problem is that the first time everything goes perfect, it finds the table im looking for and it gives me the results I want. Then i come back to check the database, and if there's nothing new on the table everything goes good, but the second the table has something in it, the program gets stuck on the line st1=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Glory) until it runs out of memory and throws an error. I'd apreciate if you had some answers to this. I'll leave some pertinent code beneath:

```
public class ComprobarArchivo extends TimerTask {
    
public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Puedo ver BD");
            //Me conecto a la base de datos a través del .java
            Connection conexionBD = BaseDeDatos.getConexion();
            System.out.println("Me conecte a la base de datos");
            String query = "SELECT Total FROM Glory";
            ResultSet rs;
            System.out.println("antes del assert");
            assert conexionBD != null;
            System.out.println("antes de hacer query");
            rs = BaseDeDatos.hacerQuery(conexionBD, "select");
            System.out.println("Veo si hay algo");
            if (rs.next()){
                System.out.println("Nuevo cobro!");
                //Llamo a la funcion cobrar de la clase main
                double cobro = 0.0;
                String cantidad = rs.getString(1);
                cantidad = cantidad.replace(",", ".");
                cobro = Double.parseDouble(cantidad.substring(0, cantidad.length() - 1));
                Main.cobrar((int) (cobro*100), rs.getString(1));
                BaseDeDatos.hacerQuery(conexionBD, "update");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No lo hay");
            }
            rs.close();
            conexionBD.close();
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        //Timer para ejecutar la funcion cada x segundos en otro plano de foma asincrona
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(this, 0, 10000);
    }
}
```

```
public class BaseDeDatos {

    public static PreparedStatement st1;
    public static PreparedStatement st2;

    public static Connection getConexion() {
        Connection myConnection;
        try {
            //creo conexion a base de dator con la libreria
            final String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            Path path = Paths.get(dir).getParent();
            System.out.println(dir);
            String aux = path.toString();
            System.out.println("antes");
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
            System.out.println("despues");
            myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + aux
                    + "\\TpvMadrid.mdb");
            System.out.println("mas despues");
            return myConnection;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static ResultSet hacerQuery(Connection conn, String tipo) throws SQLException {
        //Consulta a la base de datos y devolucion de la misma
        System.out.println("preparo statement");
        st1 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT Total FROM Glory");
        st2 = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Glory");
        System.out.println("preparo rs");
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{
            if(tipo.equals("select")){
                System.out.println("hago select");
                rs = st1.executeQuery();
                st1.close();
            } else {
                System.out.println("hago update");
                st2.executeUpdate();
                st2.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("returneo");
        return rs;
    }
}
```

Thanks again for the help

Comment: There is no line saying `st1=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Glory)` in the code you posted. What do you mean?

Comment: Also: in your `hacerQuery` method you call `st1.close()` but return the `ResultSet`. That doesn't (or shouldn't) work, because closing a statement will also close the result set.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The line i meant says `st1 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT Total FROM Glory");` sorry for the mistake. The `st1.close()` and `st2.close()` were put there after i didnt even close the statements because i thought that might have been the problem, and they work fine the first time they get something from the database